# C passing by value or reference with pointers

Tags: c, function, pointers, reference

Which function calls are passed by value and which are passed by reference?

```
int *a;

int b;

int **c;

f(a);

g(&b);

h(*c);
```

Just simple examples, I am just confused with pointers and how you tell how they are passed.

Comment: In C, all function parameters are passed by value. It's just that some values may be pointers.

Comment: So all of those are passed by value?

Comment: Formally, C doesn't have pass by reference.  It only has pass by value.  You can *simulate* pass by reference if you explicitly pass a pointer (or, it's true, if you implicitly pass a pointer, by trying to pass an array, and having the array's value decay into a pointer to its first element). So it's more a question of which parameters you *think* of as being passed by reference.

Comment: Yes, they all pass an `int *` by value.

Comment: okay thank you, but doesnt the & mean that it is passed by reference?

Comment: @SteveSummit, I think you should post your comment with some extra explanation as an answer for further readers.

Comment: `&` is used in _C++_ in a _declaration_ to say "is a reference". That concept does not exist in C. In C `&` is _only_ used to take the address of a variable, which you can pass to a function, giving the function a _pointer_ to the caller's variable.

Comment: Don't mix up with C++! That's a different language. C++ indeed knows references, and they are indeed identified by `&`. But there, `&` has double meaning, once the address-of operator, just as in C, which creates pointers, and the already mentioned references. It is context depending(!) which one is meant, e. g. `void f(int& n) { int* p = &n; }` – both united in this little example, when declaring a variable (function parameter is one as well) -> reference, otherwise, address-of.

Comment: @Aconcagua, I find your example confusing. What does it mean to take the address of a reference variable?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Hm... Possibly I'm too deep in C++, totally natural for me: `int m; f(m);` -> `p` points to `m`...

Comment: The `&b` constructs a pointer to variable `b`. The pointer is passed by value. You could think of it as passing `b` by reference, but that isn't really what is happening because the function parameter is `&b`, not `b`.

Comment: @Aconcagua, I mean `&n`

Comment: You might want to look at Reese's book "Understanding and using C pointers" -- https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/understanding-and-using/9781449344535/

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I know... If, in C++, you take the address of a reference, you take the address of the target of the reference. Thus: `n` inside f refers to `m` and thus `p` points to `m` as well. Nothing special about.

Comment: *Doesn't the `&` mean that it is passed by reference?* If anything, it proves that we're not (we can't) pass by reference.  If we were truly passing by reference, we wouldn't need that `&`.  (And in fact in C++, when you have reference parameters, you don't need that `&` in the caller; the `&` is in the function signature, indicating that a parameter is a reference.)

Answer (score 2):

Formally, C doesn't have pass by reference. It only has pass by value.

You can *simulate* pass by reference in two ways:

- You can declare a function parameter as a pointer, and explicitly use `&` to pass a pointer to an object in the caller.
- You can declare a function parameter as a pointer, and pass an array, since when you try to pass an array, what actually happens is that the array's value "decays" into a pointer to its first element.  (And you can also declare the function parameter as an array, to make it look even more like there's an array being passed, but you're actually declaring a pointer in any case.)

So it's more a question of which parameters you *think of* as being passed by reference.

You'll often hear it said that "arrays are passed by reference in C", and this isn't false, but arguably it isn't strictly true, either, because (as mentioned) what's actually happening is that a pointer to the array's first element is being passed, by value.

Comment: Passing arrays by reference: If that was fully true, then `sizeof(arrayParameter)` would yield the size of the array, not the size of a pointer, wouldn't it? @Jolly_Jimmy: Don't get confused by my comment, it *does* yield size of a pointer!

Answer (score 1):

The pedantic answer is that all of them are passed by value, but sometimes that value is an address.

More usefully, assuming there's no errors in what you have here, all of these functions are pass-by-address which is as close as C gets to pass-by-reference.  They take in a pointer as an argument and they may dereference that pointer to write data to wherever it points.  Only the call to g() is safe with just these lines because the other pointers are undefined.

This is the standard in C APIs for in/out parameters which don't need to be reallocated.

Functions that need to return a new variable-sized buffer usually take in a pointer to a pointer, so they may dereference the argument to get an address in the caller to which they write a pointer to a buffer they allocate, or which is a static variable of the function.

As mentioned in the comments it's possible to just return a pointer from a function.  Memory allocation wouldn't work in C without it.  But it's still pretty common to see functions that have size_t ** parameters or similar for returning pointers.  That might be mostly a Unix pattern where almost every function returns a success/error code so the actual function output gets shifted to the arguments.

Comment: Maybe worth to mention that we don't necessarily need an out parameter as pointer to pointer, but *alternatively* can simply *return* normal pointer...

Answer (score -1):

To make your question more clear let's initialize the variables

```
int b;

int *a = &b;

int **c = &a;
```

Then this call

```
f(a);
```

passes the object `b` by reference through the pointer `a`. The pointer itself is passed by value that is the function deals with a copy of the value of the pointer `a`.

This call

```
g(&b);
```

in fact is equivalent to the previous call relative to the accepted value. The variable `b` is passed by reference.

And this call also equivalent to the previous call

```
h(*c);
```

the variable `b` is passed by reference through the pointer `*c` value of which is equal to the value of the pointer `a`.

So all three functions accept the variable `b` by reference.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to tell is in the size of the arithmetic, but this is not so for the `char` type. For address arithmetic, the `sizeof operator` is invoked which is not the case for ordinary arithmetic as in the type of `unsigned int`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned int ui, *uiPtr;

    ui = 11;
    cout << ui << endl;
    ui += 1; //increases value by 1
    cout << ui << endl;
    uiPtr = &ui;
    cout << uiPtr << endl;
    uiPtr += 1; //increases value by sizeof
    cout << uiPtr << endl;

    return 0;
}
```